# Is my reasoning correct regarding the thermodynamic cost of separating fluids?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

I am trying to do a back-of-the-envelope calculation for the cost of separating fluids. Suppose we have 2 liter of a fully mixed fluid consisting of 50% fluid X and 50% fluid Y. Let's assume each fluid consists of 1 mole per gram. so we have 1000 moles of each.

Suppose we want to separate it into 1 liter of pure X and 1 liter of pure Y. We have to reduce the entropy of each fluid by $k_b\cdot N_A\cdot 1000 \cdot log(2)\approx 6000$ (given that $k_b \cdot N_A\approx 6$), and if we assume a 300 Kelvin heat bath, this implies by $\Delta E=T\Delta S$ that for each fluid we need about $300\cdot 6 kJ = 1800 kJ$ of energy. i.e. in total we need $3600 kJ$ of energy.
Is this basically right?

Comment: I would say it is right but remember that your assumptions are $dU = 0$ and that the fluid is ideal.

Comment: Are these fluids miscible?

Comment: @DavidWhite - if they aren’t miscible then the certainly are not ideal…

Comment: I think the ideal gas assumption should suffice for an order-of-magnitude calculation like this.

Answer (score 2):

There are several separation methods available.

Fractional crystalization - lower the temperature of the mixture until one of the components starts freezing.  If the freezing is performed slowly, pure "ice" of one of the components will come out of the solution, and that "ice" can be filtered out of the solution.

Distillation - if the relative volatility of the two components is different (practically guaranteed) you can use distillation to separate them.  Note that this takes quite a bit of energy, which can be reduced by using a distillation column with a large number of theoretical trays.

Semi-permeable membrane - if you can find a membrane that is permeable to one of the components but not the other, you can apply pressure to push one pure component through the membrane.  However, note that the osmotic pressure increases as the concentration of that component decreases, so there is a limit to how much pure component you can recover.

Molecular sieve - if you can find the correct molecular sieve, it can capture one of the components but not the other.

Without knowing more about the two components involved, I can't be more specific.  However, I can say that the separation of the fluids gets more and more difficult as the concentration of one of the species in the mixture gets lower.  From a practical standpoint, you will find that it is impossible to get absolutely pure components separated from such a mixture.  With that being the case, you need to decide on the maximum amount of "contaminant" that is permissible for each component, and that decision will strongly affect how expensive your separation process is.